# Use WHERE in JPA to query the entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Terminals implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5288308199642977991L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private int merchant_id;

    @Column
    private String terminalToken;

.....
}
```

I tried to use this query:

```
public Terminals getTerminalToken(String terminalToken) throws Exception {
        return entityManager.find(Terminals.class, terminalToken);
    }
```

Looks like it's selecting only the table key.

How I can select the table column `terminalToken`?

Comment: You could simply create a query. ``entityManager.createQuery( "SELECT t FROM Terminals t WHERE t.terminalToken=:terminalToken").setParameter(...).getResultList();``

Comment: Can you show me how I can use Java code not HQL string?

Comment: If you want to use a `JpaRepository` , you would just have to define a `List<Terminals> findByTerminalToken(String token)` method .

Comment: And call the above query?

Comment: The HQL Query will return a java List as Result. (getResultList()) If you want to build the query more object like, have a look at criteria API https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html

Comment: JPA repositories are interfaces, you only have to define a method having a name with the appropriate syntax and appropriate parameters, without body, Spring will create the implementation for you . (see here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: EntityManager#find is defined as searching on the primary key only, I wonder why you expected it to do something else.

Comment: @PeterPenzov (& others): This is not HQL. It is JPQL.

Answer (score 2):

You better use [Spring data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) to build your queries along with **[JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)**. You will just need to extend the `JpaRepository` interface, and follow the naming conventions to name your methods.

Your method will look like this:

```
public List<Terminal> findByTeminalToken(String TerminalToken);
```

Otherwise you will need to use `entityManager.createQuery()` method instead of `entityManager.find()` because the latter one is only used with the `id` column.

Comment: I don't know if switching to a (different) framework is an option. But if so, I agree with your suggestion - Spring data.

Comment: @Philipp Well we don't know if it's a choice, but it's very powerful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pure java (i am more in favour of Philipp solution) perhaps you wish to check out this solution. https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria. Sorry for not posting a direct solution but i think it woths more to give you the source.

By the way, why not using spring data? Much easier

Comment: Can you show me code example with Spring data, please?

Comment: Basically i would start my project using spring initilz (https://start.spring.io/)
add dependencies: JPA×PostgreSQL
Then add your entity.
then add a package named repositories
follow what is mentioned in spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa
interfaces inside repositories become powerfull tools.. ;-)

Comment: So web UI will call JPA repository -> will call HQL code?

Comment: yes. if this is ofcourse what you need. If not a web application spring boot and spring data may be too much...
So, it depends if you are building web application, if you are experimenting with java, etc.